# ArangoDB Import: arangoimp file crashes on run (timeout 1200)

Tags: import, graph-databases, arangodb

New to graph databases and trying to learn a few platforms for my senior project. I'm working on ArangoDB and can't seem to import data correctly.

The manual said to run the arangoimp file to execute import commands, but every time I launch the arangoimp file, it asks for a password (which is blank) and then exits with the following...

```
/Applications/ArangoDB3-CLI.app/Contents/Resources/arangoimp ; exit;
Please specify a password: 

Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529',
version 3.3.15, database: '_system', username: 'root'
----------------------------------------
database:               _system
collection:             
create:                 no
source filename:        
file type:              json
threads:                2
connect timeout:        5
request timeout:        1200
----------------------------------------
2018-09-20T19:17:30Z [25483] FATAL Collection name is missing.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Total noob here, so help is GREATLY appreciated... Working on a mac...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arangoimp` is a command line tool that needs a few arguments. E.g. the collection you want to fill and the source data.

So you should use something like:

`arangoimp --file "mydatafile.json" --type json --collection "mycollection"`

Read the [arangoimp documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Programs/Arangoimport/) for more detailed information about all options and access to remote databases.

Comment: The documentation made it seem like you're supposed to enter that command into the arango shell console but it works correctly in the terminal console if I navigate to the directory and execute from there. Thanks for trying to help a new guy!